# Error: "The given key was not present in the dictionary" when trying to see Job History on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, dictionary, sql-agent-job

I am trying to see the history of the executed jobs in SQL Server 2012 (that runs with SQL Server Agent) but I could not access any log.

The error below always appears and no log is shown:

> The given key was not present in the dictionary.

I know the history is still there because I can see some information in the table `msdb..sysjobhistory`, but I can't see here all I need to determine why one of my jobs is failing.

Has anyone experienced this before, and knows how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What service pack are you running? This looks like this was fixed in an SP. https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/709764/sql-agent-job-history-viewer-the-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dictionary-mscorlib

Comment: We are using already the SP 03 of SQL SERVER 2012.    Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      11.0.6020.0
Microsoft Analysis Services-Clienttools      11.0.6020.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      6.3.9600.17415
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.11.9600.18427
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.42000
Betriebssystem      6.3.9600

Comment: You may want to migrate this over to http://dba.stackexchange.com/, you may have better luck getting an answer to this issue.